# POSIX append with newline?

Tags: posix, sh

```
foo="thank you"

foo=$(echo "$foo"; echo "for your help")
```

Output of `echo "$foo"` is as desired:

```
thank you
for your help
```

Is there a better POSIX way to append two strings with a newline in between? This approach feels dirty.

Updates:

- I have to run on many environments and one of them rejects `echo -e`.
- I may want to append two vars, or append the result of `$some-command.sh` to a var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [`printf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html#tag_20_94)?

```
$ foo='thank you'
$ foo="$(printf "%s\n%s" "$foo" "for your help")"
$ echo "$foo"
thank you
for your help
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foo="thank you\nfor your help"
echo -e $foo
```

Comment: There is no `-e` in [POSIX `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think that the simplest way is with assignment from a double-quoted string:

```
foo="$string_one
$string_two"
```

or concatenating the output of a command:

```
foo="$a_string
$(some_command)"
```

This approach requires no extra commands to be invoked and is portable.

Comment: That will work, but personally I'm not comfortable with code that will break if its indentation is changed (for example if you later decide to enclose it in an `if` statement).

Comment: Obviously for best indenting practices, one should follow what `autoconf` does.

Comment: I don't know what `autoconf` does.

Comment: OK, then that humour was lost. It's horrendous.